# Deciding the intervals are open or closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $D^+=\{(x,+{\infty}): x \in \mathbb R\}\cup\emptyset$.

In $(\mathbb R,D^+)$, check whether the following intervals are open, closed, both open and closed, neither open nor closed.

$A=(-\infty,2]$ ,

$B=(-\infty,-3)$,

$C=\{1\}$,

$D=\{1,2\} \cup (3,4)$,

$E=(2,+\infty)$

In my opinion,

1) $A=(-{\infty},2]$ must be closed. Since the complement of $A$ is $(2,+{\infty}$), which is open, $A$ is closed. However, in $(\mathbb R,D^+)$, there is not $-{\infty}$. Does this case obstruct that we write the complement of a as $(2,+{\infty}$)?

2) $B=(-{\infty},-3)$ must be open. Since the complement of $B$ is $[-3,+{\infty})$, which is closed, B is open. My question above is also current here.

3) $C=\{1\}$ is closed. Because there is not $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $1$ here.

4) $D=\{1,2\}\cup (3,4)$ is neither open or closed. Because the complement of D consists of both open and closed sets: $(-{\infty},1)\cup(1,2)\cup(2,3]\cup[4,+{\infty})$.

5)$E=(2,+{\infty})$ is clearly open.

Comment: If you cant claim (-inf, 2] is closed because it is closed, then how are you justified is claiming (inf,2] is closed because (2,inf) is open?  How do you know (2, inf) is open?

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged the general topology tag, so I'm assuming $D^+$ is supposed to be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ composed of all open intervals with $+\infty$ as the boundary? If so, then $D^+$ must contain the set $(-\infty,\infty)$. If it doesn't, then $D^+$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. If $D^+$ is a topology then you're reasoning for part $(1)$ is correct that $(-\infty,2]$ is closed, but not correct that "there is not $-\infty$ in $(\mathbb{R},D^+)$."

For part $(2)$, how do you know that $[2,\infty)$ is closed? (Not saying it isn't, but I don't see any reasoning from you on why it should be). I'm also not sure how you can say $(-\infty,3)$ is open, since open sets are contained in $D^+$ and $(-\infty,3)$ is certainly not an element of $D^+$.

I agree with parts $(3),(4)$ and $(5)$.

Comment: Yes. $D^+$ is given as a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Okay, I understand the meaning of $D^+$. It does not mean that there is not $-\infty$ in $(\mathbb R,D^+)$. Well, I say that $[2,+{\infty}$) is closed. Because I can write the interval $[2,+{\infty})$={${x \in \mathbb R\ : 2 \le x}$}.

I want to remind to myself a property of the closed interval: If one of the endpoints is $+{\infty}$ or $-{\infty}$, then the interval still contains all of its limit points, so $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ are closed, where a,b are real numbers.

Comment: @AYARcom I believe that property is true for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but is it true for all topologies on $\mathbb{R}$? It seems to me that every $x \in\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of an arbitrary interval $(a,\infty)$. Because by the definition of a limit point, every open set containing $x$ must contain at least one point (not including $x$) of $(a,\infty)$. It is clear that $(x-\varepsilon,\infty) \cap (a,\infty) \neq \emptyset$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. This is all to say I'm not yet convinced that $[2,\infty)$ is the closure of $(2,\infty)$.